# how to take multiple input using NextLine() in java

Tags: java

how to take more inputs from user using Nextline() in java 
if i use scn.Nextline()  after reading one input it will work but giving a null in answer.

```
public class Mapdemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number of phoneaddress you want to store");
        int n=scn.nextInt();
        int j=0;
        System.out.println("enter the  phonenumber first and  then name of the person  phoneaddress");
        Map<String, Long> m1=new HashMap<String,Long>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            Long l=scn.nextLong();
            String s=scn.nextLine();
                m1.put(s,l);


        }

        System.out.println("enter the name to be checked");
        String s2=scn.next();
        System.out.println(m1.get(s2));
```

Answer (score 1):

After using .nextInt() for the first time do:

```
scanner.nextLine();
```

after that to clear the line, nextLine() stops at the newline character (OS dependant).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Comment: Typo: I think you meant "After using .nextInt() for the first time"

Comment: no it will not work

Comment: @BackSlash yea, I didn't read his code thoroughly, just reacted based on a question.

Comment: @wirelessbrain just add this line: "scn.nextLine();" after "Long l=scn.nextLong();"

Comment: if we use scn.nextLine() after it takes input but while printing it is showing null.why??

Comment: @wirelessbrain https://pastebin.com/gpLt76Xp

Comment: @wirelessbrain Here's a pic as well: https://ibb.co/gdMYVG

Comment: thanks for your effort.but try these test cases   7647464 mary lagan 5365533 smith will 665653 jhon

Comment: @wirelessbrain works fine: https://imgur.com/a/hTZjp  Can you write here what exactly you want to do, do you want for someone to enter names and phone numbers and then print those numbers out, or print both names and numbers ?

Comment: user needs to put name and phone number and then by using key that is name he/she able to get the phone number .the name may contain space.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GLAQWRVj that will print out names and numbers once you are finished entering them, to get the phone number by using name (key), you have to ask the use for the name they want to search for, then check if the map contains that name (key) and print it out if it does contain it, otherwise do something else like print "No such contact."

Comment: im facing this problem                                                                                              enter the number of phoneaddress you want to store
3
enter the  phonenumber first and  then name of the person  phoneaddress
6736363
mary logan
565768734
ronald
764763
andy jhon
enter the name to be checked
andy jhon
null

Comment: @wirelessbrain Try this code: https://pastebin.com/snVw6esC

Comment: Sure man, just don't give up, keep learning.